# How to demonstrate race conditions on an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, thread-safety

Is there a clear example that shows an `Array` failing in a multi-threaded scenario? I tried the code below, but doesn't seem demonstrate the multi-threading issues that exist in an unmanaged scenario.

```
var unsafeArray = [Int]()

func unsafeMutate() {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1000) { index in
        if unsafeArray.count < 100 {
            unsafeArray.append(1)
        }
        print("\(unsafeArray.count)") //Should not be over 100
    }
}
```

Is there a better example to illustrate threading issues in arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only has a single point of contention. Try something like this:

```
import Dispatch

var unsafeArray = [Int]()

func unsafeMutate() {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1000) { index in
        let last = unsafeArray.last ?? 0
        unsafeArray.append(last + 1)
    }
}

unsafeMutate()
print(unsafeArray)
```